# Когда точно в Lua массив (таблица только с array-part) приобретает hash-part (становится hash)?

Tags: lua

Необходимо передавать таблицы (tables) в Lua коде по сети (компьютерная мультиплеерная игра). В связи с чем очень актуален вопрос о размерах передаваемых данных (о сохранении их как можно меньшими).

Для сохранения структуры таблицы и "удержания" её в array-like стиле рекомендуют использовать table.insert, table.remove...

Имеется код (сори за форматирование, не работает в браузере):

```
local var = {}

for i = 1, 10000, 1 do
    table.insert ( var, i )
end

var[10000] = { var = 1, some = "string", another = {} }
var[555] = false
var[1] = 1
var[2] = {}
var[1] = {}
```

Вопросы:

1. Останется ли таблица <b>var</b> массивом ( таблицей только c array part ), или преобразуется в hash ( таблицей с двумя частями array и hash ). ( Сам думаю ответ "останется только с array-part",  так как структура таблицы не затронута - затронуты лишь значения элементов, но очень сомневаюсь в этом ответе, а нужно знать наверняка ).
2. Почему? :) Как это проверить?
3. Предельно уточняя: если таблица изначально имеет только array-part, то приведет ли изменение значения элемента таблицы напрямую через синтаксис `var[1] = {} var[2] = false var[3] = 1` и т.п. к изменению структуры таблицы и появлению у ней hash-part? ( При условии что заранее дано:)

   local var = {}
   for i = 1, 10000, 1 do
       table.insert ( var, i )
   end

Подозреваю, что ответ для кода выше "нет", но:

```
var[10001] = 1
```

Уже затронет структуру таблицы и создаст "накладные расходы" по памяти.
В связи с чем думаю ответ таков ( для кода выше) : до n <= 10000 код var[n] = {} не затрагивает структуру таблицы,  а значит не ведет к созданию hash-part ( таблица остается array-like). Однако код var[n + 1] = {} приведет к накладным расходам памяти (подробнее тут http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf )

Ответ правильный или нет?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Суть в том что в Lua есть только ассоциативные таблицы "ключ-значение". Она может только притворятся списком.
Посему arr['1'] = 1; arr['1000000'] = 1 не значит что таблица разбухнет аж на 999999 записей.